# Are days in Brazil shorter than in Midwest USA?

Tags: brazil, around-the-world, timezones

I live in the Midwest in The US. I have been watching the World Cup in Brazil and it seems that a lot of games end at night (after it is dark). The games are played in my time at 1:00 CDT and 3:00 CDT and I do not understand how it can be nighttime there.

Are their days shorter than ours for some reason?

The longitudes of our continents are similar so does it have something to do with the country being south of the Equator?

What about daylight savings time?

What do I need to know about days and nights in Brazil in July if I were planning to travel there instead of merely "couch surfing"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured this would be the best SE to ask at. Do you know of some better place?

Comment: There are up to +3 hrs difference in time. Its afternoon in CDT but evening in Brazil..

Comment: @John: It strikes me as a question for google, not for SE.

Comment: This is not a well-informed question but since there is now a reference to "travel," maybe it is somewhat on topic.

Comment: It is winter in Brazil, so it gets dark earlier.

Comment: Think McFly, Think! What causes the seasons? Its the Earth's tilt - its rotational axis isn't perpendicular to it's solar orbit. So when the Northern Hempisphere is tilted towards the Sun where will the Southern Hempisphere be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not night here, in most of the games. First phase they were 1PM, 5PM (which there's still daylight) and 7PM. Now they are at 1PM and 5PM. It gets dark in the middle/end of the second game, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. So it gets dark earlier in the summer there?

Comment: Brazil does not use daylight savings time like the US does.

Comment: And it's winter now in Brazil, not summer.

Comment: We have daylight savings time, but only during summer ;P

Comment: Look at the day/night map [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html). Looking at it on July 9 at 5PM PDT, all of North America is (barely) in sunlight but all of South America is in nighttime.

Comment: @DoxyLover Here's a [direct link to that date and time](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html?day=9&month=7&year=2014&hour=23&min=0&sec=0&n=&ntxt=&earth=0).